# Are there any simple app to sync a folder with google drive?

Tags: command-line, google-drive

I have a folder where i save my scripts, netbeans projects i write etc. Im tired of uploading it after every new project or every edits i make. I saw some clients but i dont want to use them.

Is there a simple command line tool where i just can pick a folder and syncs it?

Answer (score 9):

Try rclone

```
sudo apt install rclone
```

to configure:

```
rclone config
```

Rclone is a command line program to sync files and directories to and from many platforms including Google Drive. See [the official site](https://rclone.org) for a full list.

Features

- MD5/SHA1 hashes checked at all times for file integrity
- Timestamps preserved on files
- Partial syncs supported on a whole file basis
- Copy mode to just copy new/changed files
- Sync (one way) mode to make a directory identical
- Check mode to check for file hash equality
- Can sync to and from network, eg two different cloud accounts
- Optional encryption (Crypt)
- Optional cache (Cache)
- Optional FUSE mount (rclone mount)

Comment: Is this free and open source?

Comment: yes it is free and open source

Answer (score 4):

**[Grive](https://github.com/Grive/grive)**

> Grive can be considered still beta quality. It simply downloads all
> the files in your Google Drive into the current directory. After you
> make some changes to the local files, run grive again and it will
> upload your changes back to your Google Drive. New files created
> locally or in Google Drive will be uploaded or downloaded
> respectively. Deleted files will also be "removed". Currently Grive
> will NOT destroy any of your files: it will only move the files to a
> directory named .trash or put them in the Google Drive trash. You can
> always recover them.

**[Gdrive](https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive)**

> gdrive is a command line utility for uploading and downloading single
> files to your Google Drive. This tool on its own does not do
> synchronization of any kind, if you want that you can use googles own
> tool. It is meant for one-off uploads or downloads and integration
> with other unix tools. One use-case could be daily uploads of a backup
> archive for off-site storage.

Answer (score 0):

I personally like [drive](https://github.com/odeke-em/drive).

- Easy installation, because of stand-alone binary (available from the GitHub release page, which makes the installation actually easier than what the readme describes)
- Setup works via e.g. `drive init ~/gdrive`, open that URL to perform the OAuth2 web authentication, and copy credentials into prompt. The credentials are stored in that folder, so that it is a one time setup step.
- Syncing is semi automatic: Triggered by `drive pull` or `drive push`, and it asks before making local/remote changes, which makes all I/O fully transparent (good UX).

A few more solutions are mentioned in [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/lc2k57/best_way_to_sync_google_drive_to_a_folder_in_linux/).